# Swapping Twisted Client Protocol

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

In Twisted, the buildProtocol function allows me to create a class for each user. I'd like to be able to create two separate classes for each user. One for when they connect, and then another for when they're authenticated and ready to join a room and chat with clients.

Here is my current buildProtcol:

```
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        connection = self.playerManager.createConnectionClient (addr)
        return connection
```

I'd like to be able to delete this object once they authenticate themselves and transfer their existing data to a new object (`self.playerManager.createPlayerClient (addr)`).

How would I be able to swap the original object that Twisted has already stored with the new one so that the new object receives all of the data from now on?

I could easily make a boolean value (`isAuthenticated`) and then forward all the data to the new object, but I'd rather not have two existing objects at once if there's a way to destroy the original one and replace it with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The *exact* thing you're looking for – switching a Transport's Protocol out while it's running – isn't implemented yet.  See https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3204 for details.

However, what you are looking for is slightly wrong.  The Protocol's job is to parse the bytes coming in off the wire.  If you need to switch which Protocol object you're talking to in order to implement authentication, then you've given your Protocol object way too much responsibility.

Instead, have your Protocol parse the messages, and, having parsed them, delegate the actual application logic to methods on a User object.  Then, when you authenticate, switch out which User object it's talking to.  This is how Twisted itself implements authentication in IMAP, POP, SSH, HTTP, and other protocols.